# Change redirect_to format to :js in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, redirect, format

I have a controller action that should only be accessed by users that are logged in. If the user is not logged in, I want to redirect them to the login form, which an ajax-powered lightbox. Although the initial request is in `html` format, I need to change is to `js`. Right now, I'm trying it like this:

```
def new
  if user_signed_in?
    @company = Company.new
  else
    redirect_to new_user_session_path, format: 'js'
  end
end
```

Unfortunately, it's still treating the redirect as though it's in the `html` format. Is there someway to get the redirect to be treated as `js`?

Comment: Have you tried a before filter?  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html

Comment: Thanks for the tip! That cleans up my code a lot, but it doesn't address the main problem I'm having, which is changing the format from `html` to `js`. If have any more tips about that, please let me know.

Comment: I think you might have to redirect them to a page and then trigger the light osx box modal.

Comment: @simonmorley This is the approach I ended up using.

Answer (score 0):

I was try this in rails 3.2.13 n it's works, i hope it's can solve

```
if user_signed_in?
  .....
else
  if request.xhr?
    flash[:notice] = "Please login."
    flash.keep(:notice)
    render :js => "window.location = #{new_user_session_path}"
  else
    .....
  end
end
```

Comment: Unfortunately, in 4.0 this doesn't work. The `js` is still rendered as `html`, so all I get is an unformatted page with the text `render :js => "window.location = #{new_user_session_path}"`. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be looking for a respond_to block along with that before filter mentioned earlier:

```
class CompaniesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :login

  def new 
    @company = Company.new

    render json: @company, layout: false # layout false if you do not want rails to render a page of json
  end

  private

  def login
    if !user_signed_in?
     #your login code here
    end
  end
end
```

Don't forget to set your dataType ajax option to json:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "company/new" //your rails url, what is there is just my best guess
    data: query, //whatever paramaters you have
    dataType: "json", // or html, whichever you desire
    type: "GET",
    success: function (data) {
        //your code here
    }
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, the problem is that the link to "New Company" is not `remote: true`, so I'm sending a request in `html` format, not `js`. Somehow, I need to tell Rails to return the request as `js` instead.

Comment: If you just want json resturned from this controller method, all you have to do is a render json: @company, layout: false. I edited my answer to include this code.

Comment: Unfortunately, this just isn't working. Perhaps something has changed for Rails 4?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming to this and using Rails 5 I did this and this works inside the youractionname.js.erb file if one sets a @redirect variable inside the controller youractionname function when one wants to redirect.

```
# ruby control flow
<% if @redirect != nil %>
  // javascript call to use rails variable as redirect destination.
  location.replace("<%=@redirect%>");
<% end %>
```